# Java - Kerberos authentication linux

Tags: java, linux, authentication, ssh, kerberos

I am trying to connect Linux from windows using Java. Given below is the code which I have used for this process. The actual issue I am facing during session.connect() .i.e. it is prompting for Kerberos username which I have tried to enter username and password using command exec but I am not able to succeed.

I cannot skip Kerberos authentication also since this authentication is required to perform any batch operations.

Please assist me in connecting Linux by entering Kerberos username and password in an automated way.

**Java code:**

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;  

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;  
import java.io.DataOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SSHClient {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, IOException {  
        String endLineStr = " # "; // it is dependant to the server  
        String host = ""; // host IP  
        String user = ""; // username for SSH connection  
        String password = ""; // password for SSH connection  
        int port = 22; // default SSH port  

        JSch shell = new JSch();  
        // get a new session    
        Session session = shell.getSession(user, host, port);  

        // set user password and connect to a channel  
        session.setUserInfo(new SSHUserInfo(password));  
        session.connect();  
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");  
        channel.connect();  

        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

        InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

        channelExec.setCommand("ls");
        channelExec.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        int index = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(++index + " : " + line);
        }

        int exitStatus = channelExec.getExitStatus();
        channelExec.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        if(exitStatus < 0){
            System.out.println("Done, but exit status not set!");
        }
        else if(exitStatus > 0){
            System.out.println("Done, but with error!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Done!");
        }

//        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream());  
//        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());  
//  
//        // send ls command to the server  
//        dataOut.writeBytes("ls");  
//        dataOut.flush();  
//  
//        // and print the response   
//        String line = dataIn.readLine();  
//        System.out.println(line);  
//        while(!line.endsWith(endLineStr)) {  
//            System.out.println(line);  
//            line = dataIn.readLine();  
//        }  
//        dataIn.close();  
//        dataOut.close();  
        channel.disconnect();  
        session.disconnect();  
    }  

    // this class implements jsch UserInfo interface for passing password to the session  
    static class SSHUserInfo implements UserInfo {  
        private String password;  

        SSHUserInfo(String password) {  
            this.password = password;  
        }  

        public String getPassphrase() {  
            return null;  
        }  

        public String getPassword() {  
            return password;  
        }  

        public boolean promptPassword(String arg0) {  
            return true;  
        }  

        public boolean promptPassphrase(String arg0) {  
            return true;  
        }  

        public boolean promptYesNo(String arg0) {  
            return true;  
        }  

        public void showMessage(String arg0) {  
            System.out.println(arg0);  
        }  
    }  

}
```

Comment: Can you log into this host using the command-line `ssh` utility? It would be helpful for you to run "ssh -vv user@host" to log into this host, make sure it demonstrates this loging process which you're having trouble with, then [edit] your question to include the full output of that session.

Comment: I think what you've provided won't be enough to achieve Kerberos SSO. Kerberos needs to be enabled at the web application's container level, i.e., in Tomcat, JBOSS, WebSphere.  Can we take a peek at any relevant configuration file(s) where you've might have enabled Kerberos authentication in those?

Comment: @THeron WTF? This is SSH, not HTTP. He needs `gssapi-keyex` or `gssapi-with-mic`.

Comment: @jay There is no automation with username/password with Kerberos. You *have to* to use client keytab for M2M.

Comment: @Michael-O - Well, thanks...the pattern recognition program (in my head) obviously mis-fired on this one.